# Handling Global Scenarios in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a Rest Web Client todo an API call and I handle the exceptions as given below.

I want to handle 404, 401 and 400 errors in a global way rather than handling at the individual client level. How can we achieve the same.

```
public Mono<ProductResponse> getProductInformation(String productId) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("/v1/products/"+productId)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus( httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(httpStatus), clientResponse -> {
                    Mono<NotFound> notFound = clientResponse.bodyToMono(NotFound.class);
                    return notFound.flatMap( msg -> {
                        log.info(" Error Message {}" , msg.getErrorMsg());
                        return Mono.error(new NotFoundException(msg.getErrorMsg()));
                    });
                }).onStatus( httpStatus -> HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.equals(httpStatus), clientResponse -> {
                    Mono<NotFound> notFound = clientResponse.bodyToMono(NotFound.class);
                   return Mono.error(new NotAuthorisedException("Unauthorised"));
                }).bodyToMono(ProductResponse.class);
    }
```

Comment: Hey @jagannathan It's been quite a while since you asked this question. Any updates from your side? Did you try out the answer I had provided?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty forgot to update the correct answer. Accepted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Exceptions with webclients are all wrapped in **WebClientResponseException** class. You can handle that using Spring's **ExceptionHandler** annotation like this.

```
  @ExceptionHandler(WebClientResponseException.class)
  public ResponseEntity handleWebClientException(WebClientResponseException ex){
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
  }
```

Note - Here you can write complex conditional logic based on the response status, by using methods like **getStatusCode()**, **getRawStatusCode()**, **getStatusText()**, **getHeaders()** and **getResponseBodyAsString()**. Also you can get reference of the request that was sent using the method **getRequest**.

2. Using **ExchangeFilterFunction** while constructing the webclient bean.

```
  @Bean
  public WebClient buildWebClient() {

    Function<ClientResponse, Mono<ClientResponse>> webclientResponseProcessor =
        clientResponse -> {
          HttpStatus responseStatus = clientResponse.statusCode();
          if (responseStatus.is4xxClientError()) {
            System.out.println("4xx error");
            return Mono.error(new MyCustomClientException());
          } else if (responseStatus.is5xxServerError()) {
            System.out.println("5xx error");
            return Mono.error(new MyCustomClientException());
          }
          return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        };

    return WebClient.builder()
        .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(webclientResponseProcessor)).build();
  }
```

Then you can either handle the **MyCustomClientException** using **@ExceptionHandler** or leave it as it is.